# C++ table (collection) of heterogenuously types columns

Tags: c++, types, polymorphism

I am trying to build a data structure for a table or a relation (unordered table with unique rows) in C++. I have used this many times before, but have never built one myself.

So the table should be a collection of an arbitrary number of columns of arbitrary types. I can use `std::vector<some_type>` or some derived class to represent a column.

My question is what language construct can I use to define the overarching table data structure? I realize that I could somehow wrap `std::vector<some_type>` into some class which itself could derive of some base class and then represent the table as a vector of pointers to the base class, but I am kind of curious to know if there are alternative methods to do the representation, maybe using some template signature? I would rather not cast too much when using the columns of the table.

To give some background. I would be happy to use an existing data structure of the kind I am describing. I have seen such structures bring used with relational algebraic algoritmhs very aggressively in the software industry, yet I have not found such a structure in boost for example. I am specifically interested in implementing the basic relational operators on it such as join, product, etc...

Edit: Some more details. I don't want to create a data structure with row-based memory contiguity. It is important that the contiguity is column-based, so having a collection of vectors seems the right thing to do.

Comment: Did you consider having as key type a class containing an `union` of all possible -supposedly known- key types (discriminated by some other field of that class)?

Comment: *heterogeneously typed columns*

Comment: Do you mean using as the column class a class that contains the key string, i.e. the column name and the data column?

Answer (score 1):

The data structure you use can depend upon the relational operations that you will perform most commonly.

For example, if you are going to perform a join on two tables, there are multiple ways to do this.  You could use a [nested loop join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_loop_join), in which case, it's not necessary to quickly access a particular row in the table by a particular key.  On the other hand, if you use a [hash join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_join), you can quickly get a particular row by a given key.

But the choice of what type of join to use is a relevant problem in query optimization that has several factors (cardinality estimation of the data in your database, etc.).

But in general, I would do the following:

1. Create an object to represent a row in your data.  This object can have a list of the different columns that you have.  If you have a single key that you commonly perform operations on, store that in its own variable.  Otherwise, you can store a hashset of the column values for fast lookup (this is only worth it if you have a lot of columns).
2. After you have this object to represent a "row" of data, decide what type of operations you will do most often.  If you require operations that need sorting, for example, you could store these rows by a particular key with the stl **map**, which implements a red-black tree, and can get you the keys back efficiently.  If you require fast access of a particular row at a given time (eg. because of a filter in your query), then you can use a **hashmap**.

tl/dr: Storing the rows optimally depends on the type of operations you expect most frequently and your data distribution.  In any case, I think it is logical to create a class to store the concept of a "row", and then you can arrange these rows with various data structures, depending on your use case.

Comment: I think that for what I have in mind, I would favor a column based design. The most pervasive operation other than join would be an extension operation where you would add a new column by applying a function called with arguments coming from existing columns.